# Where does Chrome for Mac store its saved usernames (not passwords)?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, macos-mojave, sqlite

I tried to log into this site (superuser) today but when I clicked the username box, an email I didn't recognize popped down below mine... this is a work computer but nobody at my workplace recognizes it, and looking it up shows someone we don't know in a different state.

I checked Chrome's password section (in settings), and it's not there; I have no login/password info stored there for this site anyways, and I don't remember when I last used it.

Web searches and searches on StackExchange pointed me to open Chrome's cache or SQLite DB to find the "user history" or autofill, but the info recommended seems outdated and I'm on Mac Mojave now; there's nothing in autofill for this email, and I'm seeing a bunch of possible folders and files to open in DB Browser for SQLite, but I don't know which to open.

The closest answer I can find is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742333 - but it's from 6 years ago and the path info is either ambiguous (like *) or not matching up (probably because it's just old). Any current accurate info for this would help us squash possibly a security issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Passwords section under Autofill in the Preferences.

It's better to avoid editing configuration files when you can.

Comment: As I stated in the original post, there's nothing in autofill for this email. The email that auto-suggests for this site is not in Passwords for Chrome (which is part of Autofill) even partially... so it's being stored somewhere else, and I'm not finding where.

Answer (score 0):

It saves both usernames and passwords within a SQLite 3 database at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Login Data
```

But that won't show you anything new, as the contents you've already surfaced in the settings:

```
chrome://settings/passwords
```

Still you can `strings` all those files and `grep` for stackexchange, but I suspect your issue lies elsewhere.

Is it possible that you have a third-party password manager installed like LastPass?

Comment: There's no Profile 1, just Profile 2 and 4, which don't have a Login Data directory. The email or any chunk of it is not in chrome://settings/passwords, and neither is superuser or super... I'm not seeing how to "strings" the email or part of it, but I can try grep. I went to superuser again and clicked on the Email box and it didn't pop up again. Oh well.

Comment: Assuming you're running a recent version of Chrome, `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google` and then `du -a | grep "Login Data"` to find the DB. If you can't find it with those two commands, try the grep from your home directory.